# IBM Worklight update / migrating from version 6.1 to 6.2 error

Tags: html, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I download the new version (6.2) but when i try to run my app it show several errors as:

-No MBean found for worklight project

- files in the worklight conf server folder cannot be found
- cant deploy adapter
- can run app on server

do i need to make something especial, or there ir a guide where i can follow the steps to pass from 6.1 to 6.2??

Comment: We need to know more information about your installation in order to provide meaningful advice.  What type of application server have you deployed Worklight on, and what version of that application server?  Can we see the actual application server logs that show these errors?

Comment: As well as the Build number of the 6.2 version you're using and the java version you're using...

Comment: Also open the Worklight development server's console in eclipse via the Console view and provide the errors you see there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, i found that the issue is because the WL development server needs to be the same as my Wl version, so i return to 6.1

Comment: @lospreguntones, Please either write it as an answer or remove the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help, i found that the issue is because the WL development server needs to be the same as my Wl version, so i return to 6.1